# Add users post to their facebook newsfeed automtically with php

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have a website I'm working on. It enables users to register and post stuffs within the site. Can I get a link to some sort of api that allows people to add their facebook account (once) and then automatically post what they posted on my site on their facebook newsfeed (the sort of thing that happens when you connect your facebook account to your twitter account) .I've searched and can't seem to get exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is pretty common and if you searched you clearly didn't do a good job on the search.

Using the Facebook PHP SDK is pretty straight forward. There is a PHP Library available with a demo of the functionality you want. In your case you need to do some stuff more, so I'll explain globally what you should do:

1. Get the Facebook PHP SDK and load it into your website, determine what `scope` you need to perform the actions what you are going to do, in your case you need to have access to their timeline which is called the `publish_stream` scope. In order to get the Facebook PHP SDK working you need to create an app at http://developers.facebook.com
2. If a user grants access you need to save the authentication token that the user provides and save it in your database for later use. I'm not 100% sure how long they are valid, I think it's maximum of 30 days at the moment, but you have the ability to refresh the toking in the requests you make (correct me if I'm wrong, it's been a while..)
3. Everytime an action is done using the Facebook API you inject the usertoken in the request, thus performing the "post" action onto their timeline.

What you are looking for is pretty straight forward and easy to find..